# MUI specificity is different in storybook than in application

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I noticed that my styles on a component look right in storybook but not in the running application. The component code is at the *bottom* of this post.

All the components are from MUI, and looking at the "Computed" tab of the Chrome inspector, I can see that the `Avatar` components are getting their styles differently in the two environments -- the priorities of the classes are swapped:

In the app:
[image]

In the storybook
[image]

Wrapping the styles in `&&` fixes the problem, and I've used this solution before for MUI style issues, but I've never come across the case where it behaves differently in the app vs storybook.

Here's my main decorator in `preview.tsx`

```js
export const decorators: ComponentStoryObj<React.FC>['decorators'] = [
  story => {
    return (
      <>
        <header>
          <link
            href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,200,300,400,500,600,700'
            rel='stylesheet'
          />
          <link
            href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,500,600,700'
            rel='stylesheet'
          />
        </header>
        <AppWrapperWithUser>{story()}</AppWrapperWithUser>
      </>
    );
  },
];
```

Here's the `AppWrapper` used above, which also wraps the application itself (so that the styles match)

```js
import { ThemeProvider as MuiThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { ThemeProvider as StyledThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import { globalStyles, theme } from './theme';

type Props = {
  store?: ReturnType<typeof createStore>;
  initialState?: RootState;
};

export const AppWrapper: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, store, initialState }) => {
  const appStore = store || createStore(initialState);

  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <StyledThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        {globalStyles}
        <Provider store={appStore}>{children}</Provider>
      </StyledThemeProvider>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

And the component in question:

```js
const S = {
  Wrapper: styled(Paper)`
    padding: 32px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;Ø
    overflow: hidden;
  `,
  Pane: styled.div<{ centered?: boolean }>`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 4px;
    align-items: ${p => p.centered && 'center'};
  `,
  Subtitle: styled(Typography).attrs({ variant: 'body2' })`
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  `,
  Title: styled(Typography)`
    && {
      font-size: 28px;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
  `,
  Avatar: styled(Avatar)`
    height: 84px;
    width: 84px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  `,
  TeamLogoWrapper: styled.div`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 222px;
  `,
  TeamLogo: styled(Avatar)`
    height: 222px;
    width: 222px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    opacity: 0.3;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    position: absolute;
  `,
};

const PlayerDetailHeader = ({ player }: { player: ProcessedPropUIPlayer }) => {
  const { ... } = player;
  const infoStr = [teamName, `#${uniformNumber}`, position].join(' | ');
  return (
    <S.Wrapper data-testid={`PlayerDetailHeader-${playerId}`}>
      <S.Avatar alt={playerName} src={playerImg} />
      <S.Pane>
        <S.Title>{playerName}</S.Title>
        <S.Subtitle>{infoStr}</S.Subtitle>
      </S.Pane>
      <S.Pane centered>
        <S.Title>{openProps}</S.Title>
        <S.Subtitle>Open Props</S.Subtitle>
      </S.Pane>
      <S.Pane centered>
        <S.Title>{dollarFormatter(openAction)}</S.Title>
        <S.Subtitle>Open Action</S.Subtitle>
      </S.Pane>
      <S.TeamLogoWrapper>
        <S.TeamLogo alt={teamName} src={teamImg} />
      </S.TeamLogoWrapper>
    </S.Wrapper>
  );
};
```